# How can i update my dataframe to sort after using fillna?

Tags: python, pandas

I have used the code below to sort my dataframe.

```
class_data.sort_values(by=['Age','Gender'],ascending=[False,True], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

[image: Screenshot1]

After which, I filled the NaN values with:

```
class_data['Gender'].fillna(value = class_data['Gender'].value_counts().idxmax(), inplace=True) 

class_data['Age'].fillna(value = np.nanmedian(class_data['Age']), inplace=True) 
                                                         
class_data['Height'].fillna(value = round(np.mean(class_data['Height']),1), inplace=True) 

class_data['Weight'].fillna(value = round(np.mean(class_data['Weight']),1), inplace=True)
```

[image: Screenshot2]

The value "13.5" in column "age" is not sorted, am I able to sort this without manually typing in the same sort value operation again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to fix would be to `sort_values` after `fillna`:

```
class_data['Gender'].fillna(value = class_data['Gender'].value_counts().idxmax(), inplace=True) 

class_data['Age'].fillna(value = np.nanmedian(class_data['Age']), inplace=True) 
                                                         
class_data['Height'].fillna(value = round(np.mean(class_data['Height']),1), inplace=True) 

class_data['Weight'].fillna(value = round(np.mean(class_data['Weight']),1), inplace=True)

class_data.sort_values(by=['Age','Gender'],ascending=[False,True], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! is there any way to not have to sort the values again? since ive already sorted it beforehand